# Writing a new class with singleton

Tags: ios, singleton, uianimation

Hi I am creating a new class CNAnimations.
The purpose of this class is to perform some simple animations with ease and without using the same code a lot of times.
So, I would like it to behave like [UIView animateWithDuration...].
Should I create a singleton class and init it in the appdelegate and the access it:
[CNAnimations moveRight:view] ?
Is that correct? 
Please note that the class will be used by a lot of uilabels,textfields etc from different classes.

Simple code:

```
  -(void)moveRL:(UIView*)view{

CAKeyframeAnimation * anim = [ CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" ] ;
anim.values = @[ [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ], [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ] ] ;
anim.autoreverses = YES ;
anim.repeatCount = 2.0f ;
anim.duration = 2.0f ;

[view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
```

}

Comment: If you're going to create a singleton and init it in the app delegate, you might as well just use a property of the app delegate.

Comment: You could consider making it a category of UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C classes are also an opaque type called Class.  This allows you to not have to allocate memory and initialize a class to use a classes factory methods.  Factory methods are defined using + instead of -.  for example, `+(id)moveRL`  you often use factory methods without realizing it, such as `NSString text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"@Hello World!"]`  The `stringWithFormat` is the factory method in this example.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't seem to need an object of 'CNAnimations' and it serves more or less as a proxy for kicking off animations, you could simply define all methods at class scope (writing '+' instead of '-'). You can then do `[CNAnimation animateWhatever:]` without the need to keep a singleton.